# InvalidOperationException using Datacontext

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, datacontext, crm, invalidoperationexception

I'm getting an InvalidOperationException when I run this (it says "cannot determine the attribute name"). I have checked the net but haven't found a solution. It occurs at the foreach (var c in contacts) line.

```
DataContext ctx = new DataContext("CrmConnection");

        var contacts = from c in ctx.contacts
                       where c != null
                       select new
                       {
                           acct = c.parentcustomerid == null ? "" : c.parentcustomerid.name,
                           last = c.lastname == null ? "" : c.lastname,
                           first = c.firstname == null ? "" : c.firstname
                       };

        List<string> lines = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            foreach (var c in contacts) *ex*
            {
                Console.WriteLine(c.acct);
                Console.ReadLine();
                lines.Add(string.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", c.acct, c.last, c.first));
                Console.WriteLine(c.acct);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Error: {0}", ex));
        }
```

Let me know if you have any ideas. Thank you.

Comment: Is that the exact error message you're getting, or is there any more to it?

Comment: ex is what I added., it's not actually run. Here's the full error.

`Error: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot determine the attribute name.
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Linq.CrmQueryProvider.TranslateExpressionToAttributeN
ame(Expression exp)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Linq.CrmQueryProvider.AddConditionForBinary(QueryExpr
ession qe, IDictionary 2 filters, BinaryExpression exp, Expression parent, Boole
an negate)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Linq.CrmQueryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass2f.<TranslateW
here>b__2e(Expression exp, Expression parent)`

(rest is cut off due to character limits)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect c.parentcustomerid is an id to a related object. It does not have a property called name that you are trying to access.

You want to access the actual Customer object that "parentcustomerid" is pointing to if you want to get the parentcustomer's name.

If what you want is the account id (guessing from the acct property) then just change

```
acct = c.parentcustomerid == null ? "" : c.parentcustomerid.name
```

for

```
acct = c.parentcustomerid == null ? "" : c.parentcustomerid
```

Comment: parentcustomerid doesn't appear to be the problem. When I substitute c.address1_city for it (something I know has worked in the past for datacontext), I get the same error.

Comment: Can you post the actual schema of your db and/or your mapping code? as Reza mentioned, the exception happens in the foreach because the query is not executed until you iterate over it... the actual problem is in your query (so maybe the mapping from the your C# classes to the db is not correct)

Answer (score 0):

This exception occurred on execution of you query, when iterate on contacts context try execute your query from sql. I think this error occurred because of your context model is not mapped correctly to your database, may be different table name or property.

Comment: I think you may be right... it's just really strange because I'm using the same connection string (`DataContext ctx = new DataContext("CrmConnection");`) that was used in the code for a different function, and that one worked..

Answer (score 0):

```
where c != null
```

Is the issue.  What field are you checking for null `c.parentcustomerid !=null?`  You can't do a null check on the entity.

Also, the name property off Id will work on lookups using LINQ to Crm